# Server.MapPath does not return the right physical path mapped to a virtual directory in Web-App subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

I create a web site and mapped it to the `D:\MyWebApp` and in `Plugins` sub directory I create a virtual directory and mapped it to `D:\Project\Presentation\Web\Accounting`.
the problem is when I want to get the physical path of the`http://localhost/Plugins/Accounting` I get wrong result.

both `Server.MapPath("~/Plugins/Accounting")` and `Server.MapPath("/Plugins/Accounting")` returns 'D:\MyWebApp\Plugins\Accounting' that does not exist physically. I want to get `D:\Project\Presentation\Web\Accounting`.
I search for it and just get below lines:

1. Server.MapPath(".") returns the current physical directory of the file (e.g. aspx) being executed
2. Server.MapPath("..") returns the parent directory
3. Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application
4. Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

but in my case (virtual directory in a subfolder), it's not work !!!
I use IIS8 and Asp.Net-Mvc 4 and C#4.
how can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

try this

remove **"/plugin"**

on request `http://localhost/Plugins/Accounting` **Server.MapPath("~/")** method give path to your application folder..

```
Server.MapPath("~/Accounting/");//path to your Accounting folder
```

Comment: you want to get D:\Project\Presentation\Web\Accounting path from http://localhost/Plugins/Accounting domain or from other project like MyWebApp domain?

Comment: I want  D:\Project\Presentation\Web\Accounting path from localhost/Plugins/Accounting.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Plugins\\Accounting\\
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a virtual directory, which will reset what asp.net considers to be the base directory of your application. Does it really need to be in a virtual directory? If so, you can try checking Request.ApplicationPath to find it.